# 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'users'

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to redeem a coupon I have created on the backend and I am encountering an error in my `models.py` I am using the `django-coupons` package which has very little documentation and I am struggling a bit with it. Please help!

traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/krippee/Documents/Projects/lularippee/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/krippee/Documents/Projects/lularippee/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/krippee/Documents/Projects/lularippee/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/krippee/Documents/Projects/lularippee/main/views.py", line 198, in gift_card
    Coupon.redeem(request.POST)
  File "/Users/krippee/Documents/Projects/lularippee/coupons/models.py", line 124, in redeem
    coupon_user = self.users.get(user=user)
AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'users'
```

views.py

```
def gift_card(request):

    user = request.user

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        edit_profile = EditProfileForm(user=user)
        redeem = CouponForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            edit_profile = EditProfileForm(request.POST, user=user)
            redeem = CouponForm(request.POST, user=user)
            if redeem.is_valid():
                Coupon.redeem(request.POST)
            else:
                pass
            return render(request, 'main/profile.html', {'edit_profile': edit_profile, 'redeem': redeem})

        return render(request, 'main/profile.html', {'edit_profile': edit_profile, 'redeem': redeem})
    else:
        return redirect('/')
```

forms.py

```
class CouponForm(forms.Form):
    code = forms.CharField(required=True,
                           label=_("code"),
                           widget=forms.TextInput
                           (attrs={'placeholder':_('Code'),
                                   'class': 'text-center'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = None
        self.types = None
        if 'user' in kwargs:
            self.user = kwargs['user']
            del kwargs['user']
        if 'types' in kwargs:
            self.types = kwargs['types']
            del kwargs['types']
        super(CouponForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_code(self):
        code = self.cleaned_data['code']
        try:
            coupon = Coupon.objects.get(code=code)
        except Coupon.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code is not valid."))
        self.coupon = coupon

        if self.user is None and coupon.user_limit is not 1:
            # coupons with can be used only once can be used without tracking the user, otherwise there is no chance
            # of excluding an unknown user from multiple usages.
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(
                "The server must provide an user to this form to allow you to use this code. Maybe you need to sign in?"
            ))

        if coupon.is_redeemed:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code has already been used."))

        try:  # check if there is a user bound coupon existing
            user_coupon = coupon.users.get(user=self.user)
            if user_coupon.redeemed_at is not None:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code has already been used by your account."))
        except CouponUser.DoesNotExist:
            if coupon.user_limit is not 0:  # zero means no limit of user count
                # only user bound coupons left and you don't have one
                if coupon.user_limit is coupon.users.filter(user__isnull=False).count():
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code is not valid for your account."))
                if coupon.user_limit is coupon.users.filter(redeemed_at__isnull=False).count():  # all coupons redeemed
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code has already been used."))
        if self.types is not None and coupon.type not in self.types:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code is not meant to be used here."))
        if coupon.expired():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code is expired."))
        return code
```

models.py

```
class Coupon(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField(_("Value"), help_text=_("Arbitrary coupon value"))
    code = models.CharField(
        _("Code"), max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True,
        help_text=_("Leaving this field empty will generate a random code."))
    type = models.CharField(_("Type"), max_length=20, choices=COUPON_TYPES)
    user_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("User limit"), default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created at"), auto_now_add=True)
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Valid until"), blank=True, null=True,
        help_text=_("Leave empty for coupons that never expire"))
    campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaign', verbose_name=_("Campaign"), blank=True, null=True, related_name='coupons')

    objects = CouponManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']
        verbose_name = _("Coupon")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Coupons")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

    def redeem(self, user=None):
        try:
            coupon_user = self.users.get(user=user)
        except CouponUser.DoesNotExist:
            try:  # silently fix unbouned or nulled coupon users
                coupon_user = self.users.get(user__isnull=True)
                coupon_user.user = user
            except CouponUser.DoesNotExist:
                coupon_user = CouponUser(coupon=self, user=user)
        coupon_user.redeemed_at = timezone.now()
        coupon_user.save()
        redeem_done.send(sender=self.__class__, coupon=self)
```

Comment: I'm sorry how do you think `Coupon` model has the `users` attribute ?

Comment: `def redeem(self, user=None):
        try:
            coupon_user = self.users.get(user=user)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calling instance method `redeem` on class but not on instance. Also you are expecting `user` but passing `request.POST` It should be

```
if redeem.is_valid():
    coupon = redeem.coupon
    coupon.redeem(request.user)
```

instead of

```
if redeem.is_valid():
    Coupon.redeem(request.POST)
```

Comment: That gives me a `'CouponForm' object has no attribute 'save'` error as expected.

Comment: @Kerosive You are using `Form`, not `ModelForm` that is why. But you are setting `coupon` in `clean_code`. So we can use this. Updated answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much good sir, you are a god among men.